# jest tests fail at parsing plain HTML tags in a React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, jestjs, babeljs

Test runs break while parson standard HTML tags in jest. I am using Babel, Webpack, Jest and React Testing library.

I have installed following packages for enabling jest

```
"@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.8.3",
"@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "7.8.3",
"@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "7.8.3",
"@babel/preset-react": "7.8.3",
"@babel/standalone": "7.8.6",
"@testing-library/dom": "6.12.2",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.1.1",
"@testing-library/react": "9.4.0",
"babel-jest": "25.1.0",
```

And in `package.json` I have configured jest as follows

```
"jest": {
  "verbose": true,
  "collectCoverage": true,
  "roots": [
      "<rootDir>/resources/js/"
  ],
  "testRegex": "tests/.*.test.js$",
  "moduleDirectories": [
      "resources/js/",
      "node_modules"
  ],
  "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|scss)$": "__mocks__/styleMock.js"
  }
}
```

and since I'm running it in Laravel; I'm using `.bablerc` format for babel configuration, which has the following configuration

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "@babel/preset-env"
  ]
}
```

Here's the test that fails

```
// import dependencies
import React from "react";
// import react-testing methods
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
// add custom jest matchers from jest-dom
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
// the component to test
import BlogEditor from "../../containers/BlogEditor/BlogEditor";

// https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mocking-modules
//jest.mock("axios");

test("Blog Editor renders", () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<BlogEditor />);
});
```

The BlogEditor component has a div tag containing other input components

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="p-col-12">
            <div className="p-lg-12">
                <InputText
                    defaultValue={this.props.defaultTitle}
                    id="title"
                    placeholder="Blog Title"
                    onChange={e =>
                        this.handleInput("title", e.target.value)
                    }
                    onBlur={this.props.enableSave}
                />
            </div>
            // further details omitted...
```

The test fails at parsing the `div` tag of all things

```
Test suite failed to run

Jest encountered an unexpected token

This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

Here's what you can do:
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Details:

SyntaxError: /Code/github/website/adminpanel/resources/js/containers/BlogEditor/BlogEditor.js: Unexpected token (46:12)

  44 |     render() {
  45 |         return (
> 46 |             <div className="p-col-12">
     |             ^
  47 |                 <div className="p-lg-12">
  48 |                     <InputText
  49 |                         defaultValue={this.props.defaultTitle}

  at Parser.raise (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/location.js:41:63)
  at Parser.unexpected (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/util.js:150:16)
  at Parser.parseExprAtom (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:1123:20)
  at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:529:23)
  at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:509:21)
  at Parser.parseExprOps (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:279:23)
  at Parser.parseMaybeConditional (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:234:23)
  at Parser.parseMaybeAssign (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:185:21)
  at Parser.parseParenAndDistinguishExpression (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:1300:16)
  at Parser.parseExprAtom (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:1030:21)
```

How do I configure babel / jest to be able to parse the React components without these errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of changes, aded transform configuration to `jest` config in `package.json`

```
"transform": {
    "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
},
```

jest wans't picking up `.babelrc` but reads from `babel.config.js` so removed `.babelrc` and added js config

```
module.exports = {
    comments: false,
    presets: [["@babel/preset-env"], ["@babel/preset-react"]],
    plugins: [
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { loose: true }],
    ],
    ignore: ["node_modules"]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`import {React} from "react";` should instead be `import React from "react";`

Comment: No, it should be not, React is a default type import